# Support for Scoping and IDPList

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I would like to use the 'Scoping' and 'IDPList' options in the SAML authentication request in order to automatically select external IdP's from the applications.
Is this feature supported?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the `AuthnRequest` currently neither support `Scoping` or `IDPList`. However, The `AuthnRequest` support `NameIDPolicy`, the [code](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/81a0b4c242c3710ddfbed83bbd42d86e10177a24/src/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/Request/Saml2AuthnRequest.cs#L45). You or someone else is welcome to add the support in a [pull request](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/pulls). Then I'll look into it and add the support in a future release.

*** EDITED ***

ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 has support for `Scoping` and `IDPList` in version [4.10.9-beta1](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/releases/tag/4.10.9-beta1).

Comment: Is this offer still valid? It turns out, we need scoping too for the AUthnRequest. Mind if I make a PR?

Comment: Yes, feel free to make a pull request and I'll look into it.

Comment: any idea when you'll be able to merge it?